Remind or be patient?
So, thanks to the advice of the @keshlam, my plan was accepted (this plan is designed for approximately 3-4 months, as the head asked). He responded like this a couple of days ago:

Good afternoon, Name! Thank you for the prepared plan, it is quite suitable, and we will continue to adjust it as we go. For FPGAs, I suggest focusing on radiation-resistant models. As far as I understand, they are based on the FPGAs we are used to, so we can use Verilogs written by colleagues. If you need testing equipment, let me know! Sincerely, Mr. Professor.

But what worries and excites me. We have been communicating for a little less than a month, and during this time issues related directly to employment have not developed in any way. Yes, it seems like they are preparing an employment contract, but I am practically not involved in this. They don’t ask me for documents, any clarifying questions, nothing. The only thing I heard was “in our organization everything happens slowly because of the bureaucracy”.
Maybe it’s worth reminding or showing patience, what do you think?

Are you getting paid while they sort out their paperwork?

@GregoryCurrie No, there are no financial flows between us now. The only little work I did was write the outline that was asked for and that's it.

"it seems like they are preparing an employment contract". Have they interviewed you yet ?  Or does this job not need an interview ?

@Job_September_2020 Our interview was in this format.  I consistently called first the head, and then the employees responsible for various aspects of the laboratory.

At this point patience - you don't need to "remind" them because it's highly doubtful that they've forgotten! It has been a a couple of days (which wouldn't be a long time in normal circumstances) and they've already set expectations with you that the organization moves slowly.

The "bureaucracy" excuse is a bit worrisome. Sadly it's true for many public institutions and you need to figure out what is acceptable to you. Instead of a "reminder", ask for a timeline.

Thank you for our interest and I understand that paperwork takes time. Would be be able to lay out the individual steps we need to go through and a rough schedule so I can make my arrangements accordingly. I want to make sure I don't miss any steps on my part and want to be prepared

Take your clue from their answer (if any) and don't put the rest of your life on hold. I once applied to a EU government agency. It took them more than a year just to confirm that they had received my application. By that time I already had a different job and moved to a different continent.
